# RDF document generated by XSL. XPATH not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, rdf, rdfs

So i want to generate a RDF document applying a xslt to a xml file. I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:exam="http://example.com/">


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xml:base="http://example.com/"
            xmlns:exam="http://example.com/">

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Livro">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Cabecalho" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Subseccao" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Receita" />
            </rdfs:Class>

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Cabecalho" />

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Parte">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
            </rdfs:Class>

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Seccao">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
            </rdfs:Class>

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Subseccao">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
            </rdfs:Class>

            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Receita">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Subseccao" />
            </rdfs:Class>

            <rdfs:Property rdf:about="nome">
                <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Livro" />
                <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&rdfs;Literal" />
            </rdfs:Property>

            <rdfs:Property rdf:about="Indice">
                <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Livro" />
                <rdfs:range rdf:resource="Livro" />
            </rdfs:Property>

            <rdf:Description rdf:about="{documento/cabecalho/titulo/text()}">
                <rdf:type rdf:resource="Livro" />
                <exam:Cabecalho>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="documento/cabecalho" />
                </exam:Cabecalho>
            </rdf:Description>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="documento/cabecalho">
        <dc:title>
            <xsl:value-of select="titulo" />
        </dc:title>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and when i apply a xslt transformation to the xml file i get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://example.com/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:exam="http://example.com/">
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Livro">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Cabecalho" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Subseccao" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Receita" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Cabecalho" />
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Parte">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Seccao">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Subseccao">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="Receita">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Indice" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Parte" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Seccao" />
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="Subseccao" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <rdfs:Property rdf:about="nome">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Livro" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal" />
    </rdfs:Property>
    <rdfs:Property rdf:about="Indice">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Livro" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="Livro" />
    </rdfs:Property>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="documento" />
        <exam:Cabecalho />
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This is the xml input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE documento SYSTEM "ReceitaDTD.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rdf.xsl"?>

<documento>
    <cabecalho>
        <titulo>Receitas Tradicionais</titulo>
    </cabecalho>
</documento>
```

As you can see in the output i get `<exam:Cabecalho />` empty. Why the xpath isn't working?
I assume the problem is in here because i already made an xsl for xml and it works fine

Comment: Because your input XML has a default namespace that you are ignoring in your XPath expression.

Comment: We would have to see the XML input, too.  But don't show us the whole thing -- indeed, the XSLT you've presented is excessive, too.  Present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well, it should be quite obvious that without seeing the input, it's useless to give you any hints.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right, I forgot. I already edit the question and put the xml input.

Comment: Are you sure your actual XML doesn't have a namespace declaration in (of the form `xmlns="....")`?

Comment: Problem solved guys. Somehow my eclipse was not associating the right xml file